# webogic application class loading

Tags: linux, deployment, ear, weblogic-10.x

I had a class conflict while deploying my EAR on Weblogic 10.3.6 with a class that was in a jar coming in with the web logic. So I updated the weblogic-application.xml to have the

```
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.XXX.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

But its failing to pull the class from the new jar which I added in APP-INF/lib... Can any one suggest something, why this would not work?
Thanks!

Comment: can you specify "failing"? Do you get an exception? Can you provide a stacktrace?